# Google Analytics: why are the # of unique page views different from # of sessions of a segment on page level?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I have a page *abc123*.

Google Analytics tells me that this page *abc123* has 1000 unique page views.

I create a segment on session-level with the condition: page==*abc123*.
Google Analytics tells me that this segment has 990 sessions.

I expected that the number of unique page views were equal to the number of sessions of the segment.

How could that happen?